# The exact build configuration of pre-built OpenCV 3.1 on Windows

Tags: opencv, opencv3.1

I recently use the pre-built OpenCV 3.1.0 on Windows which was downloaded from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/3.1.0). Actually, I followed [the official installation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d52/tutorial_windows_install.html#gsc.tab=0).
The thing is that I find that the `VideoCapture` module of pre-built OpenCV processes video very slowly. It seems that it has no support of `ffmpeg`. And I find the official note:

> To use the OpenCV library you have two options: Installation by Using the Pre-built Libraries or Installation by Making Your Own Libraries from the Source Files . While the first one is easier to complete, it only works if you are coding with the latest Microsoft Visual Studio IDE and doesn't take advantage of **the most advanced technologies** we integrate into our library.

It makes me curious about what is the actual build configuration of pre-built OpenCV 3.1.0 (or other versions) on Windows. No supports of TBB, IPP, Eigen, CUDA, etc...? I didn't find any clue on the internet. Anyone knows?

Comment: There is a file named `opencv_ffmpeg310.dll` or `opencv_ffmpeg310_64.dll` in `C:\opencv-3.1.0\build\bin`. If you are using opencv along with Python you should copy either of them or just both and paste them in `C:\Python27` for example, and check the speed of the video again.

Comment: I'll try it. But my key point is that the build configuration options of pre-build opencv...